# C# WCF Remove namespace WSDL in DataMember

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, soapui

I'm trying to create a WSDL on Local Computer based End user specification XML,
Using C# and WCF i can create the WSDL XML. 
But there is a different namespace on DataContract , i want to remove the namespace on DataContract without removing it on ServiceContract.

Service Contract code :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "mws")]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IServices
{
    [OperationContract]
    string TBRequest(Header_BeginCommit Header, Data_Begin Data);
}
```

Service Behavior code :

```
public class Services : IServices
{
    public string TBRequest(Header_BeginCommit Header, Data_Begin Data)
    {
        return "Ok Guys";
    }

    public string TCRequest(Header_BeginCommit Header, Data_Commit Data)
    {
        return "Ok Guys";
    }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Header", Namespace = "")]
public class Header_BeginCommit
{
    #region Variable
    private string m_strUid;
    private string m_strRequestor;
    private string m_strHost;
    private DateTime m_dtProcessDate;
    private string m_strGuid;
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string uid
    {
        get { return m_strUid; }
        set { m_strUid = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string requestorID
    {
        get { return m_strRequestor; }
        set { m_strRequestor = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string host
    {
        get { return m_strHost; }
        set { m_strHost = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public DateTime date
    {
        get { return m_dtProcessDate; }
        set { m_dtProcessDate = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string txtID
    {
        get { return m_strGuid; }
        set { m_strGuid = value; }
    }
    #endregion
}

[DataContract(Name = "Data", Namespace = "")]
public class Data_Begin
{
    private double m_dblTimeOut;
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public double timeOut
    {
        get { return m_dblTimeOut; }
        set { m_dblTimeOut = value; }
    }

}
```

Test from SOAP UI to check the XML result (you see namespace on Header and Data) :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mws="mws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mws:TBRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mws:Header>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mws:uid>?</mws:uid>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mws:requestorID>?</mws:requestorID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mws:host>?</mws:host>
            <mws:date>?</mws:date>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mws:txtID>?</mws:txtID>
         </mws:Header>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <mws:Data>
            <mws:timeOut>?</mws:timeOut>
         </mws:Data>
      </mws:TBRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to remove name space wms from Header and Data so it can looks like this ?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mws="mws">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <mws:TBRequest>
         <Header>
            <uid>?<uid>
            <requestorID>?<requestorID>
            <host>?<host>
            <date>?<date>
            <txtID>?<txtID>
         </Header>
         <Data>
            <timeOut>?<timeOut>
         </Data>
      </mws:TBRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: In fact, I've tried removing all namespaces for your code, but found a problem: it defines this namespace as "tem". So I don't think these namespaces can be omitted here. Because I have removed all the parts of the code that can be removed in my tests, and there is not a single namespace related content.